# "man docker" displays No manual entry for docker. OS relesse is CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810

Tags: docker, manpage, centos7.6

I install docker from a binary file which is at https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-20.10.0.tgz.

I execute this command in the shell:

```bash
man docker
```

It displays:

```bash
[root@localhost package]# man docker
No manual entry for docker
[root@localhost package]#
```

How can I install docker man-documentation to my Centos system?

I tried this https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/217
but failed to execute command:

```bash
make -f docker.Makefile manpages
```

The command output are as follows

```bash
[root@localhost cli]# make -f docker.Makefile manpages
# build dockerfile from stdin so that we don't send the build-context; source is bind-mounted in the development environment
cat ./dockerfiles/Dockerfile.dev | docker build  --build-arg=GO_VERSION -t docker-cli-dev -
[+] Building 37.6s (12/17)                                                                                                                                                                  
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                   0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.39kB                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.1.7-experimental                                                                                                            8.2s
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.1.7-experimental@sha256:de85b2f3a3e8a2f7fe48e8e84a65f6fdd5cd5183afa6412fff9caa6871649c44                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.39kB                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.13.15-alpine                                                                                                               3.8s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [golang 1/1] FROM docker.io/library/golang:1.13.15-alpine@sha256:e74b83b94d499cb34c7edf55fbdff9d3cfabd238a35f9cb1b59d0e74f50b1ddd                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [esc 1/1] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build     --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod     --mount=type=tmpfs,target=/go/src/     GO111MODULE=on go get g  24.7s
 => ERROR [gotestsum 1/1] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build     --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod     --mount=type=tmpfs,target=/go/src/     GO111MODULE=on go  25.0s
 => CANCELED [vndr 1/1] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build     --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod     --mount=type=tmpfs,target=/go/src/     GO111MODULE=on go g  25.2s
 => CANCELED [dev 1/6] RUN  apk add --no-cache     bash     build-base     ca-certificates     coreutils     curl     git                                                             24.9s
------                                                                                                                                                                                      
 > [esc 1/1] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build     --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod     --mount=type=tmpfs,target=/go/src/     GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/mjibson/esc@v0.2.0:                                                                                                                                                                              
#9 1.657 go: finding github.com v0.2.0                                                                                                                                                      
#9 1.657 go: finding github.com/mjibson/esc v0.2.0                                                                                                                                          
#9 1.657 go: finding github.com/mjibson v0.2.0                                                                                                                                              
#9 24.73 go get github.com/mjibson/esc@v0.2.0: github.com/mjibson/esc@v0.2.0: Get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/mjibson/esc/@v/v0.2.0.info: dial tcp 172.217.160.81:443: connect: connection refused                                                                                                                                                                              
------                                                                                                                                                                                      
------
 > [gotestsum 1/1] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build     --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod     --mount=type=tmpfs,target=/go/src/     GO111MODULE=on go get gotest.tools/gotestsum@v0.4.0:
#13 1.790 go: finding gotest.tools v0.4.0
#13 1.790 go: finding gotest.tools/gotestsum v0.4.0
#13 24.85 go get gotest.tools/gotestsum@v0.4.0: gotest.tools/gotestsum@v0.4.0: Get https://proxy.golang.org/gotest.tools/gotestsum/@v/v0.4.0.info: dial tcp 172.217.160.81:443: connect: connection refused
------
error committing hzbnvm8bnbc2aaeohlt26ig3f: invalid mutable ref 0xc000faaca0: invalid: error committing ajz9dk7pkc11sno3lmyeoe6xg: invalid mutable ref 0xc00100e520: invalid: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c GO111MODULE=on go get gotest.tools/gotestsum@${GOTESTSUM_VERSION}]: exit code: 1
make: *** [build_docker_image] Error 1
[root@localhost cli]#
```

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Q: Is there any reason you're not installing Docker with "yum"? https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/

Comment: @paulsm4
 The OS can not access internet. Install docker from binary file  is convinent.

Comment: See my solution for offline install below.  For your particular scenario, I'd STRONGLY recommend using a package manager!

Answer (score 0):

*GOAL*: Install Docker - along with Docker man pages - on Centos 7

*CHALLENGE*: PC not directly connected to the Internet; need an "offline install".

*RECOMMENDED SOLUTION*:

> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259640/how-to-use-yum-to-get-all-rpms-required-for-offline-use
>
> Here's a specific example using "httpd" as the package to download and
> install. This process was tested on both CentOS6 and CentOS7.
>
> Install the stuff you need and make a place to put the downloaded
> RPMs:
>
> ```
> # yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly yum-utils createrepo
> # mkdir /var/tmp/httpd
> # mkdir /var/tmp/httpd-installroot
> ```
>
> Download the RPMs. This uses the installroot trick suggested here to
> force a full download of all dependencies since nothing is installed
> in that empty root. Yum will create some metadata in there, but we're
> going to throw it all away. Note that for CentOS7 releasever would be
> "7".
>
> ```
> # yum install --downloadonly --installroot=/var/tmp/httpd-installroot --releasever=6 --downloaddir=/var/tmp/httpd httpd
> ```
>
> Yes, that was the small version. You should have seen the size of the
> full-repo downloads!
>
> Generate the metadata needed to turn our new pile of RPMs into a YUM
> repo and clean up the stuff we no longer need:
>
> ```
> # createrepo --database /var/tmp/httpd
> # rm -rf /var/tmp/httpd-installroot
> ```
>
> Configure the download directory as a repo. Note that for CentOS7 the
> gpgkey would be named "7" instead of "6":
>
> ```
> # vi /etc/yum.repos.d/offline-httpd.repo
> [offline-httpd]
> name=CentOS-$releasever - httpd
> baseurl=file:///var/tmp/httpd
> enabled=0
> gpgcheck=1
> gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
> ```
>
> To check the missing dependencies:
>
> ```
> # repoclosure --repoid=offline-httpd
> ```
>
> ...

Trust me - installing from a package manager ("yum" for Centos, "apt-get" for Ubuntu, etc) - is probably *MUCH* easier.  The unix.stackexchange example above should help point you in the right direction.